# Is there any relationship between Topology and Group Theory?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

**Topology** studies the *invariants* of a system during a deformation, and **Group Theory** can be used to study the **symmetry**,  which can also be considered as some sort of *invariant*. Is there any relationship between them?

Comment: Yes, definitely. At least, there's a symbiotic relationship between the two. See the tag [tag:geometric-group-theory], for instance.

Comment: You can also look at topological groups:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-groups

Comment: [Topological methods in group theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387746111). Also: before asking at MSE you should at least try to google your question, say <topology group theory>, will give you quite a bit of material to ponder.

Answer (score 3):

An important relationship occurs for Lie groups, which are both groups and differentiable manifolds. A simple example is $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$, the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices

Comment: This is a special case of a "topological group", a subject on which whole books have been written. These are groups that have a topology which makes all group operattions continuous. They have a lot of extra structure.